# Pay multiple receiver using single checkout in PayPal

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Is there any way to pay multiple accounts/people together via PayPal from a marketplace by a single checkout request?
I found something called parallel payment but PayPal showing it's deprecated.
Suppose, I have to pay $100 where $90 will go for an account and $10 for another account. How should I do this?

There one receiver is always the same and another receiver will be variable.

Answer (score 0):

With the current REST v2 Orders API, multi-seller payments are documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/configure-payments/multiseller-payments/

Essentially you add multiple entries to the `purchase_units` array, each with their own `reference_id`